# django debug toolbar throws Improperly Configured Exception

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I have django 1.9 an django-debug-toolbar==1.3.0 installed. Here is my settings.py content

```
# debug_toolbar settings
if DEBUG:
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'debug_toolbar',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
        'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    ]

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }
```

I have validated that DEBUG is set to True. When running the server, I get the following error -

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing debug panel debug_toolbar.panels.versions: "cannot import name linebreak_iter"
```

The entire stacktrace can be found here - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a48e7c24d530118e5dfc0a75b982be2

What is going wrong? TIA.

Comment: You seem to have more settings that required. The [quick setup](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/installation.html#quick-setup) instructions would probably be enough for you. The `INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS` setting [was deprecated in 1.0](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/changes.html?highlight=INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS#deprecated-features).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debug toolbar 1.3 does not support Django 1.9. You should upgrade to [version 1.4](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/changes.html#id1) which does.

Comment: I don't see errors anymore, but the debug toolbar also is invisible.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue. You should either update your old question and remove the traceback for 1.3, or ask a new question.

Comment: Make sure you are accessing the site with `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, and that `DEBUG = True` in your settings.

Comment: Also note that if you are using bootstrap4, there is a bug that hides django debug toolbar: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/742